# 节期: jiéqī vs. jiéqí

Tags: pronunciation

I have always ever known 节期 as jiéqī.

**ABC**:

> festival season

**汉语大词典**

> 犹节日

**CC-CEDICT**

> festival season

Recently though I've heard 节期 pronounced as jiéqí and it threw me off guard a bit.

Looking through my dictionaries though I saw:

**Grand Ricci**

> jié qí
>
> Période, temps de fête; fête.

- What's the deal of the differences in pronunciation of 节期?
- What's the history of 节期's pronunciation?

Comment: Acc to zhongwen.com, 1st tone is mainland usage, 2nd tone Taiwan.  http://zhongwen.com/d/180/x193.htm  The Grand Ricci must follow Taiwan practice - doesn't it also use Wade-Giles instead of pinyin?

Comment: Native Chinese speaker here from mainland China. I think you are talking about [节气](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term). I do not know the expression 节期. If such an expression exists, the pronunciation would be jiéqī. 期 only has one pronunciation. 气 is of 4th tone. Sorry but I can't type it on my keyboard.

Comment: @MengWang I thought about 节气 first, but it turns out 节期 is used to refer jewish holidays or the sort in Chinese, which could be seen in some literatures. As a Chinese, I found that I knew very little about Jewish culture in Chinese history and I assume most young Chinese feel the same way. And as it has been mentioned in the comment of the question, the second tone for 期 is the standard tone for the character in Taiwan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is in the comment (by @neubau) of the question, not in the form of an answer.

So I guess I reiterate it here so other people would know it has been answered.

Regarding the pronunciation, the standard tone for 期(period of time, date) in Mainland China is the 1st tone and in Taiwan it is the 2nd tone. (Any mainlander who watched Taiwan TV shows when they were young would be accustomed with the Taiwanese pronunciations of words like 期(qí)待, 期(qí)許)

**Notes:**
As a native speaker, I've never come across the word 节期. So I looked it up and the common definition of it is 犹节日 an in turn 犹节日 seem to be a term for some kind of cultural (Jewish maybe?) holiday. But I'm not sure it's the name of a specific holiday or festival or a general term of such occasions (same of the sample sentences I saw imply the latter). Maybe somebody has more knowledge on this could add some comments.

Comment: Well the meaning doesn't really matter that much to me, my question is purely about pronunciation.